# How to map directory in different location?

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I have Asp.Net Web API and presentation layer as 2 different project. I am downloading an excel file having user details. The folder where the file need to be saved/created is in presentation layer like "D:\Projects\Web\WebApp\ExcelReports\ABC_.xlsx'."

But when I create the file using Web API, file try to get saved in "D:\Projects\Web\OrderApi\ExcelReports\ABC_.xlsx'."

I am creating file path as

```
  string strCompleteFilePath = HttpContext.Current
                .Server.MapPath("~/ExcelReports") + "\\" + fileName;
```

How can I create the file in Presentation layer?

Comment: Can't you just add a key on web.config and get that value and use it? Instead of "~/ExcelReports" you will have Path.Combine(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutputFolder"], fileName)

That, in my opinion, is a better solution since is more flexible and avoids hard coded strings in code

Comment: @user1845593, No, I can't do that as same method is called from hundred places :(

Comment: and you can't add the same key on all web.configs? if you do that it should work. Otherwise, I can't find other solution rather than have a common project with constants or something like